# Break query data into several files

Tags: php

I want to get table from database and then break output data by files (50 entries in each file): list01.txt, list02.txt... But somehow I got stacked at the question how to break data more effectively.

```
if ( $result = $mysqli->query($query) ) {

    icount = 0;
    while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ) {
        if ( icount % 50 == 0 ) {
            $snum = int( icount / 50 );
            $filename = 'scripts/spisok'.$snum.'.txt';
            $handle = fopen( $filename, 'w' );
        }
        fwrite( $filename, $row['uname'].';'.$row['email'].'<br />' );
        icount++;
    }

    echo 'ok';
    $result->free();

}
```

Can I just break $result into 50-entry arrays first and then write them all? Sorry, im novice to PHP

Comment: what do you do when the db data changes?

Comment: Don't forget to close your file handle.

Comment: You appear to be missing a `$` in front of `icount` everywhere and you should give `fwrite()` the file handle (`$handle`) as its first argument instead of the file name.

Comment: sorry just switching from newbie JS to newbie PHP.

when data changes it doesn't matter, I want just to get some data from db at current time. just script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use [`array_chunk`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php)

```
<?php
  if ( $result = $mysqli->query( $query ) ) {
    $data = array();
    while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result ) ) {
      $data[] = $row['uname'].';'.$row['email'];
    }
    $result->free();

    // divide an array into a desired number of split lists
    $chunks = array_chunk( $data, 50 );
    // loop through chunks
    foreach( $chunks as $index => $chunk ) {
      $file   = 'scripts/spisok'.( $index + 1 ).'.txt';
      $chunk  = implode( "<br />", $chunk );
      file_put_contents( $file, $chunk );
      // or
      /*
      $handle = fopen( $file, 'w' );
      fwrite( $handle, $chunk );
      fclose( $handle );
      */
    }
    unset( $data, $chunks );
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing particularly wrong with what you are doing except for some syntax errors here and there.

Try this :-

```
if ( $result = $mysqli->query($query) ) {

    $icount = 0;
    $handle = NULL;
    while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ) {
        if ( $icount % 50 == 0 ) {
            if ( $handle !== NULL ) {
               fclose($handle);
            }
            $snum = int( $icount / 50 );
            $filename = 'scripts/spisok'.$snum.'.txt';
            $handle = fopen( $filename, 'w' );
        }
        fwrite( $handle, $row['uname'].';'.$row['email'].'<br />' );
        $icount++;
    }

    fclose($handle);
    echo 'ok';
    $result->free();

}
```

Comment: Thanks! Surely I forgot to close handle